# Word 2010 how to make absolutely no space between lines? (example pictures included)

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

I cannot find any answers on google on how to do this. I want literally ***no*** space between lines. But to Microsoft Word 2010, no space means this:

[image: "No Space"]

But I want literally no space. Like this:

[image: Actual "no space"]

I think the problem lies here. When I highlight the text, you can see there is space above and below the text:

[image: extra space highlighted]

So then, according to the space highlighted, there is technically "no space". But there clearly is space between the actual characters in the line.

I think if the highlighting could be like this, then maybe "no space" would actually be correctly "no space" between lines:

[image: no extra space highlighted]

Things I have tried (which proved unsuccessful):

- `Highlight text -> Home tab -> Paragraph -> Setting line spacing` to `Exactly` and fidgeting with the number
- `Highlight text -> Home tab -> Font -> Advanced tab -> Position:` Raised, By: fidgeting with this number. This actually doesn't do anything.

So please, if anyone knows how to make ***literally no space*** between lines, like in picture #2, please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried setting `Highlight text -> Home tab -> Paragraph -> Interval before` and `Interval after` to 0 and setting line spacing to `Exactly` with a number just a bit lower than your font size?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirTsuverkalov that did start me in the right direction. This along with incorporating the font -> vertical positioning is what made this come out just as I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make each line a paragraph, set top and bottom margins to zero, and set line spacing to considerably smaller than font size, then you can tune (via the Font settings) the vertical position of characters.

For example, for Arial Black in 28pt size, the result is pretty close to “no space between”, without cropping letters too badly, when I set line spacing (line height) to 20.5pt and vertical position lowered 3.5pt.

Perfectness may be impossible, because even when using just capital letters, they need not have exactly the same height. To make letters *look* equally tall, typographers may make e.g. “O” extend a bit below baseline and above the capital line. Due to features of human vision, this works normally well but stops working that well when the letter is physically forced to the same height as most capital letters.

Comment: Perfect. The example was very helpful, and I was able to get my text exactly how I wanted it. Thank you very much! I love superuser!

Answer (score 0):

You need modify the paragraph parameter : Spacint interline to :"EXACTLY" 4pt, or 6pt depending on the size you want. It will obviouly crop when letter are too big.

[absoluteZeroSpace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fky0R.png)